# Broken Tile Repair

Tags: repair, tile, ceramic-tile

Is there a way to replace a toothbrush holder tile?  This is ceramic or porcelain crica 1948.[image]

The attempt to glue made the situation worse.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but it will require a hammer, chisel and a grinder. Expect a lot of dust. The brush holder is still available, so you will be able to get a replacement. Once the old one is out, it is held in place with grout.

You will need to start with a grout saw to remove the grout in the joint between the holder and surrounding tile, it will lessen the chance of chipping the neighboring tile.

Comment: Is it a DIY job or best left to the pros?

Comment: If you have never handled tile it may be best for the pros, Tile removal without chipping other tiles requires a bit of expertise. The task could easily expand into a tile repair as well.

Comment: Pretty much depends on the DIY-er. It's do-able, but (like many other things) if you're not comfortable doing it, it may be advisable to hire someone - but check references carefully, some folks do tile professionally but not very well.